# Como montar um Checkbox dinâmico

Tags: javascript, php, html

Eu tenho um:

```
<select name="snh_predio" id="snh_predio"></select>
```

Que é carregado automaticamente. Quando este é alterado:

```
$("#snh_predio").change(function() { });
```

Eu quero que imprima em uma tabela uma lista de `checkbox` para seleção:

```
echo "<input type='checkbox' value='" . $sala['snh_sala'] . "' " . $checado . " name='form_snh_sala[" . $sala['snh_sala'] . "]' id='form_snh_sala[" . $sala['snh_sala'] . "]' ";
```

Como posso fazer isso dinamicamente?

Comment: Vou deixar essa pra mais alguém responder, mas já te digo que você pode pesquisar sobre AJAX. E evite usar `echo`, o código fica meio sujo... você pode, a qualquer momento, fechar e reabrir a tag do PHP (`<?php ?>`), e tudo que estiver fora dela é texto como no `echo` -- só não precisa escapar aspas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se entendi, mas quando você alterar o < select > imagino que irá fazer uma busca com ajax dos dados das salas e com esses dados irá ter que fazer um loop imprimindo os checkbox, é isso?

Se for isso, ao buscar você pode gerar um json com os pares de chave/valor e com isso fazer um loop para gerar os html por meio do javascript ou ainda gerar o html com o php e enviar isso como uma string e imprimir na parte que precisa.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tanto utilizar um `select` do tipo `multiple`.

```
<select type="multiple">
    <option value="1">Primeira opção</option>
    <option value="2">Segunda opção</option>
    <option value="3">Terceira opção</option>
    <option value="4">Quarta opção</option>
</select>
```

Mas caso você realmente queira usar `checkbox` você terá que construir todo o elemento e toda a funcionalidade.

Independente de como você criar isso, o ideal é que você utilize [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax), pois assim você terá camadas separadas e poderá controlar tudo com mais eficiência e manutenibilidade.

Comment: Ele não poderia usar o `<input type="checkbox" name="conjunto_checkbox" value="op1"/>` e só alterar o `value`?

Comment: Dentro de um select não é recomendado, ninguém impede, mas o resultado não vai ser nada "bonito" de se ver. Além do HTML ficar todo errado

Comment: Mas eu falo no lugar do `select`.

Comment: A sim aí sim, é só uma div com vários checkbox, mas pelo o que eu entendo ele quer clicar e a lista aparecer, assim como um select faz.

Answer (score 0):

Com Javascript pura você pode fazer dessa maneira:

#### form.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function listarProdutos(categoria){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'listar.php',
                data: {'categoria':categoria},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#lista').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <select id="categoria" name="categoria" onclick="listarProdutos(this.value);">
            <option value="1">JOGOS</option>
            <option value="2">ELETRONICOS</option>
            <option value="3">ROUPAS</option>
        </select>


    Produtos:<br>
    <div id="lista"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Quando a opção do combo for mudada ele vai chamar o arquivo (exemplo `listar.php`), que pega 'entrada' do usuário faz a consulta no banco(que substituída pelos arrays, $jogos, $eletronicos e $roupas) e cria os *checkboxes* a saída HTML é retornada pelo AJAX e jogada na `div` lista. Esse exemplo é simples recomendo que se possível remover o `echo <input...` por template, uma sugestão de engine seria o [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net)

```
<?php
function imprimirCheckbox($arr){
    foreach($arr as $item){
        echo '<input type="checkbox"  name="produtos[]" value="'.$item.'" />'. $item .'<br>';
    }
}


$jogos = array('COD', 'FIFA 2014', 'NFS');
$roupas = array('CAMISA', 'CALÇA', 'BERMUDA');
$eletronicos = array('PC','NOTEBOOK','TABLET');

if($_GET['categoria'] == 1){
    imprimirCheckbox($jogos);
}else if($_GET['categoria'] == 2){
    imprimirCheckbox($eletronicos);
}else{
    imprimirCheckbox($roupas);
}
```